# Jhipster, entities created under src/main/undefined

Tags: jhipster

I have copied my project to another folder, and since, when I want to create a new entity with `yo jhipster:entity newEntity`, all the java files are created under src/main/java/**undefined**/...
Is there a way to get the initial behaviour? a way to clean my folder (if the cause is the copy of the sources in another folder).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you call "copied to another folder". JHipster stores its configuration in its .yo-rc.json file (like all Yeoman generators), so if you lost that file or messed it up, you will have this kind of error.

Comment: maybe something like this. I ran a yo jhipster on my folder in error and it solved the pb.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your .yo-rc.json the following is correctly set.

```
  {    
    "generator-jhipster": {
       ......,
       "packageName": "com.your.path",
       "packageFolder": "com/your/path",
       ......,
    }
  }
```